# Populate 2d array from wordpress queries to generate HTML content

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, wordpress-theming

(I want it like this) [For Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0E9oN.png). I dont know how to create 2d arrays where I can add section title and show several packages after that I need to show logo design heading with logo design packages and etc..

```php-template
<section id="packages" data-aos-delay="0" data-aos-duration="0" data-aos="fade" class="page-section">

    <div class="pricing-header px-3 py-3 pt-md-5 pb-md-4 mx-auto text-center">
      <h1 class="display-4" data-aos="zoom-out-up">Packages</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center mb-3">
        <?php foreach ($temp_packages as $package) : ?>
          <?php
          $title = $package['title'];
          $package_price = get_post_meta($package['id'], '_package_price', true);
          $package_subtitle = get_post_meta($package['id'], '_package_subtitle', true);
          $package_attributes = get_post_meta($package['id'], "_package_attributes", true);
          ?>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
            <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h2 class="my-3">$ <?php echo $package_price; ?></h2>
                <h4 class="my-1"><?php echo $title; ?></h4>
                <h6 class="mb-2"><?php echo $package_subtitle; ?></h6>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <ul class="list-unstyled">
                  <?php if (gettype($package_attributes) == 'array') : ?>
                    <?php foreach ($package_attributes as $attribute) : ?>
                      <li>
                        
                      </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                  <?php endif; ?>
                </ul>
                <a href="#contactUs" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Enquire</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating 2D arrays in PHP is actually very easy:

```
<?php

$myArray = [
   [
      "title" => "foo",
      "desc" => "bar"
   ],
   [
      "title" => "foo2",
      "desc" => "bar2"
   ],
   [
      "title" => "foo3",
      "desc" => "bar3"
   ],
   [
      "title" => "foo4",
      "desc" => "bar4"
   ]
];

echo $myArray[0]["title"]; // foo

foreach($myArray as $value) {
   echo $value["title"];
}

// foo foo2 foo3 foo4
```

Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I just created an Array [PHP: Arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) with all the content you need. Here is my array with one example entry:

```
$temp_packages = Array(
    [
        'id' => 12345,
        'title' => 'Some Title',
        'subtitle' => 'Some Subtitle',
        'price' => 129.99,
        'attributes' => [
            'An Attribute',
            'Some more Stuff',
            'foo',
            'bar'
        ]
    ],
);
```

The content of `$temp_packages` will probaly be stored in a database and be fetched from there.

After that, you can use your code to generate your section. I changed a bit, so it works for me:

```
<section id="packages" data-aos-delay="0" data-aos-duration="0" data-aos="fade" class="page-section">
<div class="pricing-header px-3 py-3 pt-md-5 pb-md-4 mx-auto text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4" data-aos="zoom-out-up">Packages</h1>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center mb-3">
    <?php foreach ($temp_packages as $package) : ?>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
        <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
            <div class="card-header">
            <h2 class="my-3">$ <?php echo $package['price']; ?></h2>
            <h4 class="my-1"><?php echo $package['title']; ?></h4>
            <h6 class="mb-2"><?php echo  $package['subtitle']; ?></h6>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <?php if (gettype($package['attributes']) == 'array') : ?>
                <?php foreach ($package['attributes'] as $attribute) : ?>
                    <li>
                    <?php echo $attribute; ?>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </ul>
            <a href="#contactUs" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Enquire</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: I'm getting my $temp_packages from wp_query, so i think i don't need to make these hardcoded.

Comment: So could you just `var_dump($temp_packages);` to see how your data looks like?